# Magento CE 1.9.1.0 Security Patch SUPEE-1533

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, magento-community

I am using Magento CE 1.9.1.0 and want to install the security patch SUPEE-1533, but the patch process always run in trouble with the following message:

```
sh ./PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php.rej
```

What can I do to install this patch?

Comment: **Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The security patch SUPEE-1533 is already there in magento 1.9.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think Supee-1533 is only for enterprise edition. 5344 is the one you should need